# Local breweries and brewery supplies in Istanbul

Tags: first-time-brewer, brewery, shopping

Is there any local brewery and supply shop in Istanbul? I want to start home brewing but I don't know how to find supplies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f39/brewing-beer-istanbul-first-all-grain-beer-139053/), especially the more recent posts, relates some first-hand experience of people trying to homebrew in Istanbul. Sounds like importing supplies might be a hassle with customs, and there don't seem to be many local options. Maybe the brewers at your local [Bosphorus Brewing Co.](http://bosphorus-brewing.com/) could offer some advice?

Comment: Thanks Franklin, I will visit Bosphorus Brewing Co. as soon as possible :)